# $\Bbb{R}$ with the cocountable topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Bbb{R}$ have the co-countable topology I need to show that $0\in\overline{(1,2)}$ and that there is no sequence in $(1,2)$ that converges to $0$.

Now the co-countable topology has either the empty set or has a countable complement.I established that every converging sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ with this topology is eventually constant.
Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Remember that $(1,2)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ has countable complement, $X\cap (1,2)\neq \emptyset$?. If $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of $(1,2)$ then $X-\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a neighborhood of $0$, so...

Comment: @Klara you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

If you show that $0\in\overline{(1,2)}$, you use the fact '$(1,2)$ is uncountable set'. If $V$ is neighborhood of 0, $V$ must contain point (in fact, uncountably many points) of $(1,2)$. (If not, complenent of $V$ is uncountable, and it contradicts that $V$ is at most countable.)

And let $\left<x_n \right>$ is sequence defined on $(1,2)$, Let consider $V=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $V$ is neighborhood of $0$ (because it contains $0$ and its complement is countable.) But $x_n\notin V$ for all $n$, so $\left<x_n \right>$ does not converges at 0.